# STS : Failure to create Java Virtual Machine

Tags: eclipse, macos, spring-tool-suite

I am unable to start my STS (Spring Tool Suite) on my new macOS - High Sierra Version - 10.13.6

The following are the contents of my **STS.ini** file

`-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms384m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/sts.icns
-Xmx1200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops`

1. Java version - openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
2. STS version - 3.9.6
3. Mac Version - 10.13.6

Tried adding -vm option with value `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.144_1_openJDK_macosx.jdk/Contents/Home` and changing Xmx/Xms to different values in my **STS.ini** but nothing worked. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens instead? Are all of those VM arguments correct for the JVM you have?

Comment: when I start STS , it says **"Failed to create Java Virtual Machine"**

Comment: what happens if you point the entry in the ini file for the -vm option to the java executable (including it) instead of the root folder of the JDK?

Comment: another option would be to try this with an Oracle JDK 1.8 for Mac, just to see if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 7):

open file `/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini`

add

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Comment: Make sure its in the start of the ini file. Works well.

Answer (score 7):

Faced a similar issue when I upgraded Java from Java 8 to openjdk 14. I resolved it by doing the following:

Open `/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini`

Add the following lines to the start of the file and save it:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Now, you need to point the softlink of `libjli.dylib` inside `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.jdk/Contents/MacOS/` to the right location. To do that, do the following:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.jdk/Contents/MacOS/
sudo rm libjli.dylib 
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib libjli.dylib
```

Now, try opening SpringToolSuite4 and it should work seamlessly. If you are using another version of jdk, make sure that the path is chosen correctly in the ini file as well as the softlink creation part. *Note: You do not need to play around with vmargs to adjust the -Xms and -Xmx args to resolve this.*